# Force Bootstrap to render mobile friendly

Tags: google-apps-script, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm working on a responsive design using Google Apps Scripting and have run into some issues.  All site contents are piped through an iFrame sandbox that prevents me from setting up a meta viewport.  This means that no matter what device I view the application on, it's treated as a desktop application.

For example, viewing the web app on a Galaxy S4 shows the full 1080x1920 view.

Google creates the sandbox iframe and sets it to the resolution of the device.  They don't let you create a meta element and creating it via JavaScript won't do you any good as you can't modify contents outside of the sandbox.  Once the page has loaded, you can scale the window and the elements will resize as expected, but this does me no good on a mobile device.

The best I can come up with is to retrieve navigator.userAgent after the page has loaded and then modify each element after the fact.  Far from ideal.

So, is there a way to trick Bootstrap into rendering mobile or am I stuck writing media queries and custom CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem (within a modal, not iframe) so created a pretty lengthy but basic css page to solve it:

https://github.com/shawntaylor/bootstrap-force-device

Once you add that css file to your project, you call `force-xs` (or `force-sm`, `force-md` or `force-lg`) on a parent div of the content you want to force. Then the CSS forces the inner content to behave like it's on an `xs` device.

```
<span class="force-sm">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <h1>I want to make this behave like it's on an sm device</h1>
    <h2>Even when it's on a desktop</h2>
    <p>Or within a window that thinks it's a desktop</p>
    </div>
</span>
```

Comment: I like it but I also need the fonts to scale as well.

Comment: makes sense. You should be able to dig into bootstrap css and see font sizes load at specific widths...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the link handy, but I literally just read about this:

You can download a version of Bootstrap CSS that only includes the mobile media queries, and delete the media query so that the mobile CSS loads on all devices.